# Is it Possible to Alias a Const Value in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a value that I want to re-use for a number of assertions later in the test, but wanted to access it without having to nest everything under the function that sets it.

```
cy.url().then(($url) => {
            const moveKey = $url.match(/mvus.+?(?=\/)/);
```

Seems like the way to do this would be to alias the value, but not sure if that's possible?

Comment: Did you try it? `cy.url().as('url')` and more generally `cy.wrap(myConstant).as('myConstant')`.

Comment: I tried wrapping, the value I got back was `Object, Object`, not the `const` value.

Comment: Ok, that sound like the the jQuery wrapped value, if so can be accessed from index 0. I'll try it out and post an answer if my theory is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since learned about the awesomeness of `let` in Javascript.

```
let moveKey;

cy.url().then(($url) => {
            moveKey = $url.match(/mvus.+?(?=\/)/);
```

`moveKey` is now accessible throughout the file, ES6 for the win!